# Mencoder Mp4(x264) Encoding

Tags: video, x264, mencoder

I want to convert any video to mp4(x264).But codecs of videos which will be processed are different(x264,Xvid,etc.). I want that properties of video which I convert should be same with video which I will convert and I want to not raise video's size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ffmpeg` for it. Below statement is just example. And reference this link. http://juliensimon.blogspot.com/2009/01/howto-ffmpeg-x264-presets.html

`$ ffmpeg -i [input file] -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -acodec libfaac -vpre slower [output file]`

Comment: I need to convert videos with embedded subtitle with mencoder.